# How to change attribute href after click on link and load page JQUERY (Wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I try to change the URL link (`href` attribute) when I click on a URL after following link and loading page. I tried this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/ASC/" class="sort_loading_country">link</a>
```

```js
jQuery( ".sort_loading_country" ).click(function() {
    str = jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href") ;
    if ((str.indexOf('ASC') + 1) > 0) {
        new_str = str.replace(/ASC/g, "DESC");    
        jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href", new_str);
    }
});
```

This changes the URL, but after clicking on the link open new page with new url. I want change the URL after opening page and following the link. I tried this too:

```
jQuery(".sort_loading_country").click(function() {
    str = jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href");

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if ((str.indexOf('ASC') + 1) > 0) {
            new_str = str.replace(/ASC/g, "DESC");
            jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href", new_str);
        }
    });
```

The same behavior, click on the link - then open new page with new url. I want that when I click on the link open page with old url and after that change url to new in href.
Am I missing anything ? Anybody knows how to change attribute href after loading page with old URL ?

Comment: does way #2 not work?

Comment: Your `a` element has 2 `href` attributes

Comment: You have to wrap `jQuery(document).ready()` around **all** the references to jQuery. It should be the top level wrapper

Comment: Sorry, deleted href. Yes, way2 not working:(

Comment: Anybody knows how to change attribute href after loading page with old URL ?

Comment: For example I have link
<a href="http://example.com/ASC/" class="sort_loading_country">link</a>
When I click on this link I want thet open http://example.com/ASC/ and after this change http://example.com/ASC/ to http://example.com/DESC/ in a href (change attribute href http://example.com/DESC)

Comment: This jsfiddle.net/h7q0z2Lq not working in WORDPRESS, I don't understand why. I don't have any errors. I use JQuery instead of $. But if I use this code open page example.com/DESC and don't change in attribute hred ASC to DESC!

Answer (score 0):

The main error being (as mentioned in comment), the `$(document).ready()` needs to wrap all jQuery code.

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7q0z2Lq/)

**N.B:** I have substituted `jQuery` reference to `$` in that jsFiddle. You can use either

Comment: not working. If you click on link you open page http://example.com/DESC/ 
must be http://example.com/ASC/

Comment: In wordpress this don't work , really strange:( I don't understand why. 
I added your code and add this 
(function($) {

//code 

})( jQuery );
for using $ instead of JQuery()

Comment: This jsfiddle.net/h7q0z2Lq not working in WORDPRESS, I don't understand why. I don't have any errors. I use JQuery instead of $. But if I use this code open page example.com/DESC and don't change in attribute hred ASC to DESC!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - so the onclick function is being called before the link is followed, so you're changing the URL and then that URL is being followed. What you need to do is delay the execution of your code such that it happens AFTER the URL is followed.

You can do this by using the setTimeout method like so:

```
jQuery( ".sort_loading_country" ).click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        str = jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href") ;
        if ((str.indexOf('ASC') + 1) > 0) {
            new_str = str.replace(/ASC/g, "DESC");    
            jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href", new_str);
        }
    }, 1);
});
```

This will delay execution of your code until after the link is followed.

Comment: Also, it's bad practice to use the selector to get your elements over and over again. You should assign the result of jQuery(".sort_loading_county") to a variable and then reuse that variable so that you're not querying the dom over and over again in search for the same element.

Comment: In this case don't change url, open old page, but don't change attribute href:(

Comment: That's because the page is reloading - you're not opening the link in a new tab. The code can't be run after the page loads - it's a new page! You'd have to instead modify the page server-side.

Comment: If I open the link in a new tab url don't cahge - I have the same URL in attribute href. Do you have any idieas how can solve this problem ?

Comment: This https://jsfiddle.net/h7q0z2Lq/  not working in WORDPRESS, I don't understand why. I don't have any errors. I use JQuery instead of $. 
But if I use this code open page http://example.com/DESC/ and don't change in attribute hred ASC to DESC!

Comment: If I had to guess you're running into a jquery conflict and $ is not defined. See this link: https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above, the first click will be /ASC/ and if you click it again it will be /DESC/.

```js
jQuery( ".sort_loading_country" ).click(function() {
 console.log($(this).attr("href"));
    setTimeout(function() {
        str = jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href") ;
        if ((str.indexOf('ASC') + 1) > 0) {
            new_str = str.replace(/ASC/g, "DESC");    
            jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href", new_str);
        }
    }, 1);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to work with storage like if user has clicked the link and whenever he comes back it will directly change the `href`.

```
<a href="https://example.com/ASC/" class="sort_loading_country">link</a>

if(localStorage.getItem("url", "DESC")){
    str = jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href");

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if ((str.indexOf('ASC') + 1) > 0) {
            new_str = str.replace(/ASC/g, "DESC");
            jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href", new_str);
        }
    });
}
jQuery(".sort_loading_country").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("url", "DESC");
    alert(jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href"))
});
```

JsFiddle URL

https://jsfiddle.net/8f8dL72v/

Comment: I found solution
var str = location.href;
if (str.indexOf('ASC') + 1){
    var new_str = str.replace(/ASC/g, "DESC")
    jQuery(".sort_loading_country").attr("href", new_str);
}